# partition function - using each number once and using only odd numbers

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

1)I was asked to find a partition function , where each number appears only once.

for example, for n=2 - 1+1 is not good but 2 is.

I think the function is : 
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+q)^k$,what do you think?

2)I was asked to find a partition function , where only odd numbers can appear.

for example, for n=2 - 1+1 is  good but 2 is not.

I think the function is :

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1/(1-q^{2k-1}) $,what do you think?

3)I was asked to show that the partition function , where each number appears only once equals to the partition function , where only odd numbers can appear.

I tried to begin like this :
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1/(1-q^{2k-1})=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+q)^k $

and I got to:
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(q^k (q^{k-1}+q^{2k-1}-1)/(1-q^{2k-1}) $
but now I am stuck

Comment: $(1+q) = (1-q^2)/(1-q)$

Comment: In part 1) you want (1+q^k) instead of (1+q)^k. Read [OEIS sequence A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009).